# Style @Users and #hashtags on textareas

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to add # for hastag and @ for user and I am using below package for that in ember
package: ember-cli-mentionable

**working**

```
     let hashTags = {
              token: '#',
              values: hashTagList
            };
    {{mentionable-input config=hashTags value=test placeholder="Add comment here"}}
```

**Not Working**

```
let hashTags = {
              token: ['#','@'],
              values: [hashTagList,userList]
            };
```

Please help me to find the solution for multiple token

Comment: there is typo `['#',@']` it should be `['#','@']`

Comment: not working with ['#','@']

Comment: @kumkanillam I changed my description

Answer (score 0):

this problem is resolved by
[https://yakmada.github.io/ember-cli-mentionable/dist/][1]

```
mixedConfig: [
  {
    values: ['Johnny', 'Syd', 'Steve', 'Paul']
  },
  {
    token: '#',
    values: ['noAmpersand', 'atSucks', 'poundThis', 'hashBrowns']
  }
],
```